The Master Tetrist
This is part 70 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a diagramless crossword with Tetris mechanics. Fill the grid by placing the given pieces in order (row by row, left to right), so that at least one cell of each piece has either another piece or the grid border directly below it. Pieces must be placeable by “dropping” them from the top of the grid and moving them left and right (but not upwards) as they fall. Pieces may be rotated but not mirrored. Draw some separating lines into the finished grid to create a rotationally symmetric crossword whose answers, using normal crossword ordering, correspond to the clues below. Three answers are unclued, marked with question marks.
Today I have visited a forested nature reserve. I have hiked around a very photogenic lake, visited the entrance to a famous cave, and spotted some deer at a respectful distance. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. DEA agent, in slang (4)
4. "In your dreams!" (2,2)
7. Dark-brown shade contained in, but unrelated to, the name of England's northernmost county (5)
10. What to do after taking ten paces and turning, perhaps (4)
11. ??? (7)
13. Tendency to seek pleasant breaks from the real world (8)
16. He may or may not have shot first, depending on the version watched (3)
17. A major export of Sri Lanka (3)
18. Smartphone software platform, or an island in the Aegean Sea (3)
20. A boy's name, according to Johnny Cash (3)
22. ??? (8)
24. Most considerate (7)
26. Body part protected by a bevor (4)
27. Crown —, a prized possession (5)
28. Painter of the "Black Paintings" (4)
29. ??? (4)
Down
1. A system such as the 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 etc. for the down clues here (9)
2. Lure into a trap, as an army (6)
3. Wrestler John with the Guinness record for most wishes granted through Make-A-Wish foundation (4)
5. Body of water; one is named after Vitus Bering (6)
6. Not many (3)
8. Body of water; one is named after Henry Hudson (3)
9. A member of Sauron's army, perhaps (3)
12. Discussing the weather, say (5,4)
14. Contra- (4)
15. Currency symbolised by $ or ₱ (4)
19. Like fingers after eating an ice block, often (6)
21. More straightforward (6)
23. After taxes (3)
24. She's everything; he's just — (3)
25. Like a bass singer's voice (4)
26. Complain incessantly (3)

Gladys will return in Bazaars and Bananas.

Gladys is at

 Burabay National Park in Kazakhstan, visiting Kenesary Cave.

Here is the filled in grid:

 

Answers to clues:
Across

 1. DEA agent, in slang (narc)
 4. "In your dreams!" (as if)
 7. Dark-brown shade contained in, but unrelated to, the name of England's northernmost county (umber)
 10. What to do after taking ten paces and turning, perhaps (draw)
 11. ??? (burabay)
 13. Tendency to seek pleasant breaks from the real world (escapism)
 16. He may or may not have shot first, depending on the version watched (han)
 17. A major export of Sri Lanka (tea)
 18. Smartphone software platform, or an island in the Aegean Sea (ios)
 20. A boy's name, according to Johnny Cash (sue)
 22. ??? (national)
 24. Most considerate (kindest)
 26. Body part protected by a bevor (neck)
 27. Crown —, a prized possession (jewel)
 28. Painter of the "Black Paintings" (goya)
 29. ??? (park)

Down

 1. A system such as the 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 etc. for the down clues here (numbering)
 2. Lure into a trap, as an army (ambush)
 3. Wrestler John with the Guinness record for most wishes granted through Make-A-Wish foundation (cena)
 5. Body of water; one is named after Vitus Bering (strait)
 6. Not many (few)
 8. Body of water; one is named after Henry Hudson (bay)
 9. A member of Sauron's army, perhaps (orc)
 12. Discussing the weather, say (small talk)
 14. Contra- (anti)
 15. Currency symbolised by $ or ₱ (peso)
 19. Like fingers after eating an ice block, often (sticky)
 21. More straightforward (easier)
 23. After taxes (net)
 24. She's everything; he's just — (ken)
 25. Like a bass singer's voice (deep)
 26. Complain incessantly (nag)

I must say I did not use the tetris aspect at all, but just solved the first few clues across/down and worked from there.

The filled grid:

 

The three unclued entries spell

 BURABAY NATIONAL PARK, a tourist destination in Kazakhstan.

